# preg_replace( '/\h+/', ' ', $foo ) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove excess horizontal whitespaces (spaces and tabs) but preserve line-breaks in javascript?

With PHP: `preg_replace( '/\h+/', ' ', $foo )`

```
A   lot   of   text text   text     text
A lot more  text     text text     text       text
```

Should look like:

```
A lot of text text text text
A lot more text text text text text
```

Comment: Note that your original code doesn't actually contain any tab characters - currently, it contains only plain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a character set that contains both a tab character and a space:

```js
const str = `A   lot   of   text text   text     text
And more  text     text text     text         text`;
console.log(
  str.replace(/[  ]+/g, ' ')
);
```

Or, with the `\t` metacharacter instead:

```js
const str = `A   lot   of   text text   text     text
And more  text     text text     text         text`;
console.log(
  str.replace(/[ \t]+/g, ' ')
);
```

Comment: Well, that was easy! Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious why you chose to use a literal tab in place of `\t`.  Does that buy you anything?

Comment: @Dummy JS doesn't support `\h`, and `\s` will mean that newlines will be replaced as well.

Comment: @vol7ron No, but you're right, probably better to use `\t`

Comment: Ahh, I was trying to think if there would be (1) any performance benefits (2) better support for certain OSes — but couldn't think of any.  Just because I don't know, doesn't mean they don't exist :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use the double-negative `/[^\S\n]+/` to look for whitespace characters that aren't a newline:

```js
let str = `A   lot   of   text text   text     text
A lot more  text     text text     text       text`
console.log('before:',str)

// use a double negative (not a word character or newline)
str = str.replace(/[^\S\n]+/g,' ')
console.log('after:',str)
```

I'm not sure if this would capture all the conditions for the different kinds of spaces (en, em, etc) as it would depend on how JavaScript regex treats `\S`, but this is probably safer than all the other answers listed so far.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = `A   lot   of   text text   text     text
And more  text     text text     text         text`;

console.log(
  str.replace(/[ \t]{2,}/g, ' ')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
outp = str.replace(/[ \t]+/g,' ');
```

This filter all extra spacing and tab